# Convert an Eclipse "Makefile project from existing code" to an AVR project

Tags: eclipse, avr

If I have a C project that was imported into Eclipse as a CDT "Makefile project from existing code", how can I turn it into an AVR project, so that I can set the AVR options in the Project Properties?

If I create a new C/C++ project, the AVR options are present, but I want to import my existing Makefile code, not recreate the project.

Answer (score 3):

Close the project and add the following to the `.project` file:

```
<nature>de.innot.avreclipse.core.avrnature</nature>
```

This goes at the end of the `<natures>` section in that XML file. Re-open the project and the AVR nature will have been added, and you can then see the AVR options. [Source](http://www.avrfreaks.net/index.php?name=PNphpBB2&file=viewtopic&p=776634).

Comment: Worked for me with Eclipse Oxygen (4.7.1)