# Missing Toolchain settings after creating AVR project from existing source in Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, project, avr

After cloning source from github, I have created project with existing code, but I cannot set it up to AVR projet. 
I've tried creating "Makefile project from existing code" with choosing AVR toolchain, and edditing `.project` file by adding

```
<nature>de.innot.avreclipse.core.avrnature</nature>
```

(solution found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17174368/convert-an-eclipse-makefile-project-from-existing-code-to-an-avr-project)), but in Project Properties -> C/C++ Buid -> Settings still there are only tabs with Binary Parsers and Error Parsers. If I create project from scratch (new AVR cross target application) everything is fine.

Is there any other way of changing project type after creating it?